# The mb command requires a URL that specifies a bucket

Tags: google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I'm attempting to use the `mb` command to create a bucket on Google Cloud Storage but am getting

```
CommandException: The mb command requires a URL that specifies a bucket.
```

The odd part is that while

```
gsutil mb gs://foo/bar1
```

returns this error,

```
gsutil ls gs://foo/bar2
```

correctly lists files in `gs://foo/bar2.` I don't see how `gs://foo/bar2` can be a valid URL while  `gs://foo/bar1` isn't. Is anyone able to shed some light here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`gs://foo/bar1` is a URL that specifies an object, `bar1`, within a bucket, `foo`.  The `gsutil mb` command requires a URL signifying a bucket, e.g. `gs://foo`. The `gsutil ls` command can accept both bucket and object URLs.

Answer (score 0):

`gsutil mb` makes a bucket. "gs://foo" specifies a bucket, specifically the bucket 'foo'. "gs://foo/bar1" specifies an object rather than just a bucket. "foo/bar1" isn't a bucket.